# My Vue library is not working after published

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, plugins

I'm trying to create vue library. It works as expected but not when it's published in NPM.

I imported `json` file in `nigeriaStatesLgas.vue` but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically, the package does not work when I `install` it from the npm repository.

The `states` property from the image below is supposed to be populated.

[vue devtools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCByl.jpg)

Here is the repo to the package.

[repo](https://github.com/Cejowisz/vue-nigeria-states-lgas)

Comment: what are the commands used to publish the component?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim `npm publish`

Comment: i mean to generate the component like `npm run build` or `npm run bundle`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim `npm run build`

Comment: i think that you didn't publish it properly, i seen in your `package.json`  this line `"main": "dist/vue-nigeria-states-lgas.js"` i recommend to change it to `"main": "./dist/vue-nigeria-states-lgas.js"`